# passing react hooks into component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. I'm trying to add additional functionality of deleting the record from the list by setting the value.

here is my **App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "./data";
import List from "./List";

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovie] = useState(data);

  return (
    <main>
      <section className='container'>
        <h3>{movies.length} Movies to Watch</h3>
        <List movies={movies} setMovie />
        <button onClick={() => setMovie([])}>clear all</button>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In List.js, Im trying to delete the record when clicking on Watched button. Can I call setMovie inside the List component? is it a correct way?

**List.js**

```
import React from "react";

const List = ({ movies }, setMovie) => {
  return (
    <>
      {movies.map((movie) => {
        const { id, name, year, image } = movie;
        return (
          <article key={id} className='person'>
            <img src={image} alt={name} />
            <div>
              <h4>{name}</h4>
              <button
                className='btn'
                onClick={(id) =>
                  setMovie(movies.filter((movie) => movie.id !== id))
                }
              >
                watched
              </button>
              <p>{year}</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

[image]

Comment: maybe add status in movie obj like 'watchStatus' and change the status form true to false when click on watch. because by filtering it will just remove the movie form the list, right?

Comment: Looking at your components, besides the correction @Nicholas Tower already mentioned, I would suggest you split up your List component into a List and a Card component. Just a general separation of concern kinda thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code. First:

```
<List movies={movies} setMovie />
```

This shorthand assigns a value of `true` to setMovie. To assign the setMovie function to it, you must instead do:

```
<List movies={movies} setMovie={setMovie} />
```

And secondly this:

```
const List = ({ movies }, setMovie) => {
```

Should be this:

```
const List = ({ movies, setMovie }) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<List movies={movies} setMovie={setMovie} />
```

this way the funcition will appear in the List component as a prop.

The way you were doing, it will just appear as `true`